# iPad Childviews still see incorrect bounds in landscape mode even in viewDIdAppear

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have created 2 child views inside my view controller to be swapped between each other based on 2 different buttons.

a la, button 1 shows childview1 etc.

However, when I start the app in landscape mode and print out the bounds for the childviews in viewDidAppear, the bounds are still incorrect.

So basically,

1. In view controller's viewDidAppear method, i create 2 childviews, then i immediately print out bounds here for the viewcontroller.  they are correct.
2. In the childviewcontroller's viewDidAppear method, i also print out the bounds AFTER i know they are correct for the parent and they are still incorrect.

so the output looks like this..

```
ViewController Bounds Height2:748.000000 Width: 1024.000000   
Child Bounds Height:1004.000000 Width: 768.000000
```

and when the app loads, my viewcontroller has correct dimensions, and the childs do not.

Any ideas?  is there some way to set the childs boundaries on creation?

Thanks

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the child view controllers' frames? i.e. `childview1.frame = parentView.bounds` or by using `initWithFrame:`?

Comment: i'm setting the size with the line self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

Comment: And that line of code is within your child view controller?

Comment: yes.  inside the viewDidAppear method. the problem seems to be that the bounds (according to the child) are still set at portrait rather than landscape, even though the parent that created the child, sees the bounds are set on landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you never set your child view controllers' views' frames from anywhere outside of the child view controllers. Within your parent view controller's `viewDidLoad` method (or the `viewDidAppear` method, if you like) and after the child view controllers have been initialized, set their frames using the parent view controller's `bounds`.

For example, you might put the following in your parent view controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
childViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 50);
```

Comment: boom, that is exactly what i was looking for.  this got it.  Now if i can just figure out why the second child doesn't adjust after rotation  if it hasn't been viewed yet ill bet set.

Comment: views do not get automatically rotated or resized unless they are subviews of a parent view that is resized. I would suggest that you create both child view controllers in `viewDidLoad` for your parent controller. Then, set both views frames as above AND add both views as subviews of your parent view. Now use the `UIView` `setHidden:` method to hide one view initially and to control the swapping of the child views later as well.

Comment: I see.  Yeah currently I am not adding the child views until the button is pressed.  So I will go ahead and make that change as well.  Thanks.